# CanoScan LiDE 110 driver for Ubuntu? How to scan via command line?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, usb, command-line, scanner

**CanoScan LiDE 110** is connected to my Ubuntu 11.04. I need to scan remotely using the command line.

How can I use the scanner from the command line?

Tried/Failed/Succeed:

```
$ apt-get install sane sane-utils
$ scanimage
scanimage: no SANE devices found
$ scanadf
scanadf: no SANE devices found

$ sane-find-scanner
failed... over and over to find the correct one.. (very strange)

$ dmesg 
now found something...(after waiting a lot)


$ scanimage -L
device `genesys:libusb:001:018' is a Canon LiDE 110 flatbed scanner

$ scanimage -x 100 -y 100 --format=tiff > /tmp/scanBabyscan.tiff
$ file /tmp/test.tiff
 /tmp/test.tiff: TIFF image data, big-endian
# ll /tmp/test.tiff
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1393802 2011-10-25 20:09 /tmp/test.tiff
```

**Follow up:**

what is what:

```
PPM = color
PBM = black and white
PGM = gray
```

how do i use it show me some examples:

```
scanimage -d umax:/dev/sgb --resolution 72 -x 200 -y 100 > scan.ppm
          |______________| |_____________|
              device       DPI 72,120,300,600

scanimage --mode=color > /tmp/test.tiff
          |__________|
           color
```

Comment: Are you saying you need the driver for the scanner as well?

Comment: Run `scanimage --list-devices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `scanimage` program.

If you install the 'sane' package, you can also use the `scanadf` tool.

To find the scanner use `lsusb` and `sane-find-scanner`.

http://www.sane-project.org/man/scanimage.1.html

http://www.martoneconsulting.com/sane-scanadf.html

Comment: Its not HP products. Its a Canon.

Comment: please see above, does it mean its working? But few times it did not show my USB and its product details.

Answer (score 0):

- PPM = portable pixmap format
- PBM = portable bitmap format
- PGM = ortable graymap format

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format